# How to change the direction of the div animation to the clicked direction and then continue animation in that direction?

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I want to animate the div which is already in animation state towards the click direction and then the animation should continue in that particular direction.

Here is the link of what I did.

```js
var $follower = $("#follower"),
    mouseX = 0, 
    mouseY = 0;

$(document).click(function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY; 
   $follower.stop().animate({left : mouseX, top: mouseY});
});
```

```css
#follower{
  position : absolute;
  background-color : red;
  color : white;
  padding : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="follower"></div>
```

Comment: Where is the code? What have you tried? Please check this [How to ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have attached what i have tired in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `window.requestAnimationFrame`:

If you want you can also match the `speed`. But this is another level ;-)

```js
var $follower = $("#follower"),
    mouseX = 0, 
    mouseY = 0,
    vector = { x:0, y:0 },
    isFirst = true,
    speed = 0;

$(document).click(function(e){
   mouseX = e.pageX;
   mouseY = e.pageY;
   vector = {
    x: $follower.offset().left - mouseX,
    y: $follower.offset().top - mouseY
   }
   speed = Math.sqrt( Math.pow( vector.x, 2 ) + Math.pow( vector.y, 2)) * 0.0001;
   $follower.stop().animate({left : mouseX, top: mouseY}, init );
});

function init() 
{ 
  if (isFirst) { render(); }
  isFirst = false;
}

function render()
{
  var left = $follower.position().left -  vector.x * speed;
  var top = $follower.position().top -  vector.y * speed;
  //  Never leave the page
  if ( left < 0 && vector.x > 0 ) { left = $(window).width() }
  if ( left > $(window).width() && vector.x < 0 )  { left = 0 }
  if ( top < 0 && vector.y > 0 ) { top = $(window).height() }
  if ( top > $(window).height() && vector.y < 0 )  { top = 0 }

  $follower.css({ left: left, top: top })
  window.requestAnimationFrame( render )
}
```

```css
#follower{
  position : absolute;
  background-color : red;
  color : white;
  padding : 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="follower"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @barbieri .:-). But please if you can say how to make it stay into an big container only and don't let speed to increase.

Comment: Square now doesn't leave the page. To get the proper speed you should do some extra work which is outside the scope of your question. I'm sure you have a good starting point now.

Comment: Furthermore you should use something like [TweenMax](https://greensock.com/tweenmax) instead of jQuery `animate` 'cause it performs better.

Comment: Another thing: if you use `transform: translate()` instead of `top` and `left` you can exploit the GPU instead of the CPU which is a lot faster. See --> https://youtu.be/-P28LKWTzrI

Comment: Just for fun I tried to add dynamic speed. It's not quite right though as you need some more wotk to set up accordingly to `animate`. But it's a good starting point for you, even better than before.

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I'l see to it.Thanks for the advice:-)